# Problem installing Swarm

Tags: swarm, installation

I have a problem installing Swarm. when i enter 
`sudo apt-get install ethereum-swarm` i get a problem saying :

> dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ethereum-swarm_0.3.1+build14601+xenial_amd64.deb (--unpack):
>    trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/swarm', which is also in package swarm 2.1.6-1
>   
> dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

Is there anybody who knows how to fix this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is being discussed here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/17295
See there for more details.

The quickest solution is to do:

```
apt-get --purge remove ethereum
apt-get --purge remove swarm
apt-get install ethereum
```